# Shadow on UIImageView issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying set a `cornerRadius` and shadow of an `UIImageVIew` that's inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`. The problem is that I set `clipToBounds = true` and that stops the shadow and the `cornerRadius`.

I want to have cornerRadius, clipToBounds and shadow of the images. Not sure what I'd doing wrong here.

```
class PostPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var selectedImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    selectedImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    selectedImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    //applying overall shadow to image
    selectedImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    selectedImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    selectedImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    selectedImage.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    selectedImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `UIView` as a shadow container and add your `UIImageView` to that. The following is an example of what you need to make shadow and corner radius work together with `UIImageView`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 128, height: 128))
    shadowView.clipsToBounds = false
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, cornerRadius: 6.0).cgPath
    view.addSubview(shadowView)

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")
    imageView.frame = shadowView.bounds
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    shadowView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: I get the cornerRadius, but no shadow. I tried `selectedImage.layoutIfNeeded()` and `self.layoutIfNeeded()`  but still nothing. Just corner radius

Comment: Pls try again with my revised answer. This time I set `masksToBounds = false`

Comment: I tried. But it's not working. I get the shadow but not the `cornerRadius`. But from what I read, you cannot set cornerRadius and shadow on the same image view. It's more complicated than that

Comment: I updated my answer. It's already been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try : 
selectedImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

check for the aspectMode and check clip subviews.

[image]

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are give corner Radius and shadow both on imageview, is not work. Try to use imageview inside view and then give corner radius on view and shadow on imageview